# Give custom markers a static width and height (non scalable markers by zooming)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on a google maps implementation, in my case i don't want to scale my custom markers by zooming in and out. Does anybody knows how to fix this?? I want them to stay the same width and height as i give them.

Here the code:

```
 function Icon(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(30, 30); // scaled size
    this.origin = new google.maps.Point(0,0); // origin
    this.anchor = new google.maps.Point(0, 0); // anchor
}

var icon1 = new Icon('img/marker-1.png');
var icon2 = new Icon('img/marker-2.png');
var icon3 = new Icon('img/marker-3.png');
var icon4 = new Icon('img/marker-4.png');
var icon5 = new Icon('img/marker-5.png');


for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0].lat, locations[i][0].lng),
        icon: icon1,
        //size: new google.maps.Size(100,100),
        map: map
    });
```

Comment: markers by default don't scale when a map will be zoomed

Comment: when you would post some code I might be able to tell you

Comment: @Dr.Molle here you go